Не могу задеплоить проект ASP.Net на timeweb cloud
Может кто помочь. Не могу задеплоить свой проект ASP.Net с гитхаба на timeweb cloud. Выдаёт ошибку в логах деплоя(на последней строчке)

Не может определить порт приложения, хотя сам проект на декстопе запускается без всяких проблем. Я менял конфигурацию файлов по следующему образцу:
(проект называется API-Server)
Файл API-Server.csproj:
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <RootNamespace>API-Server</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="8.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

API-Server.http:
@app_example_net_core_HostAddress = http://0.0.0.0:5083
GET {{API_Server_HostAddress}}/weatherforecast/
Accept: application/json

###

appsettings.Development.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}

В appsettings.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

И в launchSettings.json:
﻿{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:1804",
      "sslPort": 44349
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5083",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:7070;http://0.0.0.0:5083",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}

Изменение конфигурация ни к чему не привело, ошибка в логах деплоя та же. Что я делаю не так? И есть ли какие либо гайды по тому как приготовить проект ASP.Net к развёртыванию на сервере?
